# Как найти точку на отрезке?

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

У меня есть отрезок с известными координатами концов. На этом отрезке есть точка. Я знаю расстояние от начала отрезка до этой точки. Мне надо найти координаты этой точки.  Как найти эти координаты?

Пример: Есть 2 точки А(3,3) и В(6,4). Длина отрезка примерно 3,16. И есть точка С(?,?) на отрезке. Как найти координаты, если от А до С =1,8 ???

Comment: Задачи на пропорцию, 6-й класс - http://www.mathematics-repetition.com/6-klass-mathematics/6-1-2-zadatchi-na-proportsiyu.html

Comment: @StateItPrimitive - нет, не загнул, не сложнее. Отношение разницы координат между точкой и началом к разнице координат между концом и началом равно отношению расстояния от точки до начала к расстоянию от конца до начала.

Comment: Пример: Есть 2 точки А(3,3) и В(6,4). Длина отрезка примерно 3,16. И есть точка С(?,?) на отрезке. Как найти координаты, если от А до С =1,8 ???

Comment: Я Вам уже написал. Код - сами.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Алгоритм без кода (довольно элементарный):

Имеем:
Две точки `A`, `B`; `len` - расстояние от точки `А` до требуемой точки `C`

```
full_len = |B - A| // длина вектора, соединяющего две точки == длина отрезка
C = A + (B - A) * (len / full_len)
```

Сложение векторов и умножение на число - очевидные операции.

Comment: мне кажется, что человек имел в виду систему координат x - y, в которой ваше решение не может работать

Comment: ДА!!! ДА!!!  ДА!!!

Comment: @Blacknife вообще-то ответ дан для N-мерной системы координат. И двухмерная система (x,y) сюда вписывается

Comment: Пример: Есть 2 точки А(3,3) и В(6,4). Длина отрезка примерно 3,16. И есть точка С(?,?) на отрезке. Как найти координаты, если от А до С =1,8 ???

Comment: @Andryxa находите [длину отрезка](http://mathprofi.ru/vektory_dlya_chainikov.html) _AB_, затем находите соотношение расстояния от точки _А_ до _С_ (у вас уже имеется длина отрезка _AC_) к длине отрезка _AB_, пусть это будет _relLen_. Затем находите координаты вектора _BA_ (т.е. _B - A_), затем умножаете на _relLen_ и к результату прибавляете координаты точки _A_. Таким образом вы найдете смещение относительно точки _A_ посредством пропорции отношения длин отрезков.

Comment: Вообще-то да, решение верно для любой размерности. Не думал, что такие очевидные вещи надо объяснять.

Comment: @int3 , @newman : Если всё же в задаче у человека точки A, B и C каждая имеют по координате`X` и координате `Y`, то чтобы использовать вашу формулу, нужно прогнать её сначала по оси X, затем по оси Y, но вы удивитесь наверное, что в такой системе координат расстояние от точки А до точки С ( `len` ) чаще всего может иметь длину, которая не будет одинаково сопоставляться с обоими осями, в связи с чем мы будем иметь ложные значения. Я не понимаю, как Вы будете это использовать, хоть убейте.

Comment: @Blacknife Дак расстояние от точки _C_ до _A_ находится как квадратный корень суммы квадратов разностей координат этих точек (это стандартный способ найти длину отрезка), т.е. вам не надо пробегать отдельно для каждой оси, вы считаете все за раз.

Answer (score 11):

Имеется отрезок `AB` с координатами `A(Xa, Ya)` и `B(Xb, Yb)`.
Требуется найти координаты точки `C(Xc, Yc)`, лежащей на отрезке `AB` на расстоянии `Rac` от точки `A`.

```
Rab = sqrt((Xb - Xa) ^ 2 + (Yb - Ya) ^ 2)
k = Rac / Rab
Xc = Xa + (Xb - Xa) * k
Yc = Ya + (Yb - Ya) * k
```

---

*Обозначения:*
**`f ^ n`** - возведение `f` в степень `n`, в нашем случае (первом) `f` будет `Xb - Xa` и `n` будет `2`.
**`sqrt(f)`** - квадратный корень из `f`, в нашем случае `f` будет `(Xb - Xa) ^ 2 + (Yb - Ya) ^ 2`.
**`f / n`** - деление `f` на `n`, в нашем случае `f` будет `Rac` и `n` будет `Rab`.
**`f * n`** - умножение `f` на `n`, в нашем случае (первом) `f` будет `Xb - Xa` и `n` будет `k`.

Comment: k = Rab / Rac.? а не rас/rab?

Comment: @Andryxa Поправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

nodet - точка конец вектора, в твоем случае точка b 
nodef - точка начало вектора, в твоем случае точка a

```
dx = nodet.x - nodef.x 
dy = nodet.y - nodef.y 
dz = nodet.z - nodef.z
r = math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2 + dz ** 2) 
xx = dx * (step/r) 
yy = dy * (step /r)
zz = dz * (step /r)
newnode = node(nodef.x + xx,nodef.y + yy,nodef.z + zz)
```

newnode - новая точка на заданом расстоянии